# Animate a object by scrolling

Tags: animation

I know how to animate a object with CSS, but I want to control it with scrolling. So lets say I have box that I want to rotate by scrolling down and past it. How can I do this with or without JavaScript.

Example (three green icons on under the video): http://www.zendesk.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/

or

http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/

Scroll down to check all the features that they have and at the bottom is more information about them or/and how to use them.